# Any filter we can use in tcl script?

Tags: tcl

I have a question about the for loop,

```
for {{set loop 0} {$loop < 100} {incr loop}} {
    #do someting here
}
```

loop goes from 0 to 99, and I do something for each value of loop, but if the loop is 3, I will skip it, so, is there any filter in tcl to achieve it or we should write it as:

```
for {{set loop 0} {$loop < 100} {incr loop}} {
    if {loop != 3} {
        #do someting here
    }
}
```

Comment: The `for` command takes 4 arguments, so remove the "outer" braces around the first three.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "continue" command. For example:

```
for {set loop 0} {$loop < 100} {incr loop} {
    if {$loop == 3} continue
    # do something here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
% proc xiter {varName "over" a z "excluding" filter body} {
    upvar 1 $varName i
    set excl [lsort $filter]
    for {set i $a} {$i < $z} {incr i} {
      if {[lsearch -exact -sorted $excl $i] < 0} {
        uplevel 1 $body
      }
    }
  }
% xiter loop over 0 10 excluding {5 3 8} {
  puts $loop
}
0
1
2
4
6
7
9
```

Comment: With Tcl 8.5, you can use the [`in/ni` operators](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/expr.htm) to test list membership, which will greatly simplify your code: `if {$i ni $filter} {uplevel 1 $body}`

Answer (score 1):

The first, third and fourth arguments to `for` can be arbitrary scripts, so you could do this:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 100} {incr i [expr {$i == 2 ? 2 : 1}]} {
    do stuff with $i ...
}
```

Comment: While true, that code hides the intent. I have to stop and think for a several seconds to understand that `{incr i [expr ...]}` actually means "skip the number 3". But you are of course correct that the third argument can be anything you want.